# Error pushing changes to my own remote repository (authentication problem)

Tags: linux, git, github

I am a newbie using git. I have recently changed of computer, and by mistake, during the transition I deleted my local repository. To retrieve the repository on my new computer I have used:

```
git init
git remote add origin <repo_address>
git pull origin master
```

Of this way I got the files again in my computer, but now when I try to make a change locally and upload it to my own remote repository it gives me the following message:

```
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

  git push --set-upstream origin master
```

I think that it is an authentication problem since in no step I have been required to enter any password to verify that I am the owner, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: You need to do exactly what its telling you to do. Next time you push set the upstream.

Comment: It is not authentication problem, it's a minor configuration problem that's easy to fix. [`git push -u`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt--u) or [`git branch u`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--ultupstreamgt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local repository has no upstream at the moment.
You can fix this by running the command shown in the error message.

```
$ git push --set-upstream origin master
```

After which, you should be able to run `git pull` and provide authentication if necessary.